# Firing two functions from an event listener (one throttled, the other not)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, throttling

I have an event listener for scroll events that fires  a function responsible for appending an element to the viewport. That same scroll event listener is being throttled to prevent a downpour of scroll events (more manageable). The library being used to throttle is [`throttle-debounce`](https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce). Problem: throttling `handlePageScroll` is throttling everything contained in that method (of course).

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(2000, this.handlePageScroll));
}

handlePageScroll = () => {
  someFn() // logic for appending an element, does not need throttling
  this.loadNextBatch(); // logic that actually needs to be throttled
};
```

I've tried throttling from within `handlePageScroll` with no success. Is there way to fire two functions from an event listener?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, by keeping a state:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let throttled = false
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (!throttled) {
      throttle(2000, () => {
        this.loadNextBatch()
        throttled = false
      })()
      throttled = true
    }
    someFn()
  })
}
```

Comment: This looks fantastic, except for some reason using an arrow function inside the event listener causes the throttle to break. It fires a multitude of times compared to when it was just `addEventListener('scroll', throttle(2000, this.handlePageScroll))`

Comment: Oh yes you're right, that's a bug on my end. I'll edit my answer with a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: @Jose I've updated with a solution now. I haven't been able to test it, but hopefully it works for you!

Comment: no dice. There's something off with trying to call `throttle` in any other way besides the way I have it currently^. I don't understand why though. It should be returning a throttled copy of whatever function you pass into it. From there you should be able to call it like any other function.

`const throttled = throttle(2000, this.loadNextBatch);`
`throttled();`

Comment: Ah so it returns a function that you invoke? Adding a simple `()` at the end of the `throttle` call should be enough (immediately call the returned function), see my updated answer.